# how to Set connection timeout while invoking soap client

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Am new to webservice. I had written a soap client and it was working fine. But when the server hosting the web services is not responding we are getting a Failed to access wsdl at the location "" Got Connection timed out: connect while opening stream issue after 25 seconds. During this 25 sec browser hangs up. So i want to restrict connection timeout to 5 seconds. How can i set this to 5 seconds? Below is my code

```
URL url=null;
try {
url = new URL(serviceUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return "ERROR";
}

Service service = new Service(url);//Exception is thrown here
ServiceSoap soap = service.getServiceSoap();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    url = new URL(serviceURL); // serviceURL is like "http://.../some.asmx"
    String actionUrl = "http://.../SomeService";
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000); //5 sec in milliseconds
    connection.setDoOutput( true );
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", actionUrl);

    String file = (String)request;

        OutputStream reqStream = null;
        try {
            reqStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        try {
            reqStream.write(file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        InputStream resStream = null;
        try {
            resStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

For org.apache.cxf you can try below code

```
Service service = new Service(wsdl);
ServiceSoap port = service.getServiceSoap();
HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
policy.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
```

Comment: But Service service = new Service(url); will not accept connection as parameter. i did connection.getUrl(). But same issue. It takes 25 seconds

Comment: why do you use connection.getUrl() ?

Comment: Service class is part of client stubs. Service service = new  Service(URL wsdlLocation). We have to give wsdlLocation as a parameter. How can i use URLConnection here?

Comment: Are u using user defined  Service class or http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html?

Comment: If this is from the client stub, then it should have the method to connecting to the location itself.

Comment: Yes.Service service = new Service(URL wsdlLocation) is the method connecting to the location of the WSDL. But this method is throwing connection timeout issue. So there a way to set connection time?

Comment: Can u please provide the Service java code? or could you please provide me from which API are you getting the Service class file? I can decompile and check

Comment: For example - org.apache.axis.client is having a Service class. If that axis2 then you can use http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#timeout_config reference. Therefore I need from which API are u using the Service class?

Comment: <plugin><groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generate-sources</id>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<wsdlOptions>
<wsdlOption>
<wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/ABCD.wsdl</wsdl>
<wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/ABCD.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
<extraargs><extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
<extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
<extraarg>-p</extraarg>
<extraarg>com.rk.client</extraarg>
</extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
</configuration>
<goals>
<goal>wsdl2java</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

Comment: I used above Maven Plugin to generate client Stubs